# Magento 2 : How to add a billing address details in checkout under payment method

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, billing-address

> I'm using Magento 2.4.6. I want to add billing address info under the
> credit card payment method as it is showing for cash on delivery
> method, shown in the screenshot.

[Screenshot1](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/40812722?key=012efb3108f47cb8e767926fc0792fd7)

[Screenshot2](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/40812682?key=6ff01df32d78af3bbb583357dbdd3b2b)

> The checkout configuration has an additional Display Billing Address
> On option (Stores -> Configuration -> Checkout -> Checkout Options).
> It is already set to **Payment Method - billing address is displayed
> per payment method.**

Let me know if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: have you used a default payment method or a third party?

Comment: Added third party method element payment

Comment: Look like you are using a custom payment method, you have to review that extension and make it work by yourself.